# Apache2: "Address already in use" when trying to start it ('httpd.pid' issue?)

Tags: linux, apache2, httpd.conf

Using Apache2 on Linux, I get this error message when trying to start it.

$ sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start

```
httpd not running, trying to start
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: unable to listen for connections on address 127.0.0.1:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

$ sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl stop

```
httpd (no pid file) not running
```

Some facts:

- This is one of the last lines in my Apache logs:

  [Mon Jun 19 18:29:01 2017] [warn] pid file /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
- My '/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf' contains
  Listen 127.0.0.1:80
- I have "Listen 80" configured at '/etc/apache2/ports.conf'
- Disk is not full
- I've checked that I do not have two or more "Listen" at '/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf'

Some outputs:

$ sudo ps -ef | grep apache

```
root      1432     1  0 17:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1435  1432  0 17:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1436  1432  0 17:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
myuserr   1775  1685  0 17:37 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

$ sudo grep -ri listen /etc/apache2

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:# Include list of ports to listen on
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:Listen 80
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:    Listen 443
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:    Listen 443
```

What can I do to restart Apache? Should I repair 'httpd.pid'?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that something already uses 80 port. 
If you really don't have 2 line of `Listen 80` in apache configurations then execute this command to see what uses 80 port: `netstat -antp | grep 80`.

Comment: tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1425/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 192.168.1.8:80          192.168.1.9:42832       SYN_RECV    -                   
tcp6       0      0 192.168.1.8:80          192.168.1.9:42830       FIN_WAIT2   1428/apache2

Comment: 192.168.1.9 is the IP address of my PC. 192.168.1.8 is the IP address of the webserver

Comment: Now I have only "tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1425/apache2"

Comment: You can kill apache service by sudo kill -9 -1425 and try to start again

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by killing the three processes

```
root      1621     1  0 18:46 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1624  1621  0 18:46 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1625  1621  0 18:46 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

However, each time I want to reboot my server, I must kill thee processes. What is starting them?